# TeX Archaeology - Installing historic/old TeX Live Releases

Tags: texlive, installing

I've inherited an old TeX tree that contains multiple versions of TeX and I'm attempting to determine what local changes were made to specific versions. I understand that in certain cases our binaries were patched in addition to any local style files.

I'm currently looking at our TeX Live 2011 tree. This was installed using the internet installer back when that release was current.

My original plan was to install the archived historic release of TeX Live 2011 and then compare the two directory structures to highlight our local changes.

Since the archived TeX Live 2011 tree also contained files for the internet installer I attempted to run these with the slight chance these might install TeX Live 2011 similar to our original release. This does not work.

Is there a way to install TeX Live 2011 to replicate most of our original installation tree? Or should I be looking at the ISO images?

I realize this is not a common request. I'm attempting to pick up this TeX tree and determine what others have done in the past.

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Older releases are available: ftp://tug.org/historic/systems/texlive -- but I've never used them so far. There are ISO images amongst them.

Comment: It's easy to replicate either the DVD release (from the archived ISOs) or the final internet update release (ISO then do an update using the historical archive). If you need to aim 'between' these you will probably have to read the TL SVN to see what was added when.

Comment: I've managed to install the ISO and figured out how to update it using the historical archive. Unfortunately I need a snapshot that's earlier than the final version of the historic archive. Is there a way to point the update mechanism at an SVN archive that's checked out to a certain point in time.

Comment: Using the SVN tree and --revision argument I've managed to recreate the non-local portion of the tree. I'm reading through the build guide and much of this seems to depend on building the sources from scratch. What I'd really like to do is take the binaries and texmf sources I've extracted and create a distribution tar file. Is this possible? I'm wondering if I should post a new question.

Comment: This is more a comment than an answer (can't comment because of reputation) but the login and password for the ftp does note work anymore. (I wonder if its had even work once in the past...) I really wonder how I can access old version so far...

Comment: Both `anonymous` and `ftp` work for the username; the password can also be empty. As far as I can see, the site is alive and well.

Comment: @Welgriv **For What Its Worth** I have no problems opening those links without password using Internet Explorer which allows me to open those folders in windows file explorer just as if its a local directory. so it may be down to browser/user rights

Answer (score 14):

The archive on ftp://tug.org/historic/systems/texlive has the historic versions of TeXLive (and so LaTeX of course too) dating back to 1996 until the current release, as of writing TL 2018.

In case there is a password query popping up (thanks to the information by Joseph Wright):

> Username: anonymous
>
> Password: ftp

You will find an ftp archive then, with the individual releases.

The 1997 directory seems to be empty, however.

The newer releases have both `.tar.gz` bundles or `.iso` images, the older ones partially only `.tar.gz` or `.iso` images.

Comment: Are the historic TeXLive versions mirrored somewhere?

Comment: In case people have issues with FTP not being supported, https://www.tug.org/historic/ lists some mirrors, amongst them a few that can be accessed via HTTP.

Answer (score 1):

- This is an updated version of user31729's excellent answer which links to a so-called **FTP server**.
- As of 2022-11-05, browsers like Chrome and Firefox have **removed FTP support**, see [here](https://www.howtogeek.com/744569) and [here](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/thread/112696966) (Google Support website) for example.
- In **Windows** (and **macOS**), you can use your OS' **file explorer** (`Win + E`), see screenshot. Just copy `ftp://tug.org/historic/systems/texlive/` in the address field.
- In my case, there was *no* need to enter the **login data** (user name: `anonymous`, password: `FTP`).

[image]