# Where can I find old versions of book.cls?

Tags: packages, document-classes, ctan, tex-history

I'm looking for a copy of book.cls, version "1996/10/31 v1.3u".

My goal is to port the changes made to a local copy of book.cls "1996/10/31 v1.3u" used in a legacy project to the newest version.

The question [Historical, stable version archive of packages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31886/historical-stable-version-archive-of-packages) pointed me to https://ctanmirror.speedata.de/ but the oldest book.cls there is "2007/10/19 v1.4h", which is what I have in MacTeX 2016 (but it says "2014/09/29 v1.4h").

Comment: You may look here: ftp://ftp.tug.org/historic/macros/latex-saildart, but that is reallllllllllllllllllllllly old ;-)

Comment: I don't have Mac, but you have `book.cls` from 2007 in your MacTeX 2016?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, see my edited answer. It's v1.4h but dated 2014.

Comment: That's the same version I have here on TL 2016

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/258478/tex-archaeology-installing-historic-old-tex-live-releases

Comment: @JosephWright, good tip but the oldest book.cls there seems to be "2004/02/16 v1.4f".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Download the file ftp://ftp.tug.org/historic/macros/latex2e/latex2e-19961201/base.tar.gz which contains the version of `book.cls` that you want. To actually generate `book.cls` you have to extract the archive, open a terminal into the directory containing all the files and run the command:

```
latex classes.ins
```

This command generates some files, among which the `book.cls` you want.

Comment: I actually enjoyed it! xD

Answer (score 5):

I've found version "1997/10/10 v1.3x" at ftp://tug.org/historic/systems/texlive/1998/TeXLive3/texmf/tex/latex/base/book.cls

Comment: The link ask for username and password.

Comment: @ThomasGuénet, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/347087/324. But I've used it in Chrome and it worked once. It did work with wget.

Comment: @ThomasGuénet Username/Password “ftp”