# The last version of 32 bit MikTex

Tags: miktex, miktex2.9

I know that 32 bit MikTex is discontinued but I have to install it on a PC which does not support the 64 bit architecture. Where can I find the last version of the 32 bit Windows binaries? In particular, I need the Net installer in order to get the complete MikTex, so I am assuming the file is `setup-5.1.exe`.

Comment: Have you considered asking this question on the [official MikTeX site](https://miktex.org/)? Incidentally, which OS do you run on the PC in question?

Comment: Win 10 2016 LTSB 32 bit.

Comment: You can find [old MiKTeX releases on github](https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/releases). But AFAIK only the source code and I do not know, how to compile and install. AFAIK you would also need a history package repository, but I don't know if there is anyone. For TeX Live there are complete [historic distributions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/258478).

Comment: @cabohah I don't think that you need a historic package repository, miktex is not organized like texlive. If you find a 32 bit installer (e.g. on older dvd) it should be able to access and use the normal repository.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer But are there 32bit binaries, e.g., for `biber` and `bibtex` in the normal repository?

Comment: @cabohah good question, probably not, but as long as you don't try to update binaries it could nevertheless work (if you find an installer with binaries naturally). But on the whole, I would try a texlive 2022 instead.

Answer (score 1):

While this is not an answer to the original question, it does solve the problem.

1. Download some 32 bit installer, e.g., [here](https://store.horje.com/download/110953). In this case, it's the basic version.
2. If this version is not willing to update/download packages (my case), download all the packages using the most recent Net installer on a 64 bit machine.
3. Copy the folder with packages to the 32 bit machine, and use it as a repository to install all the packages or choose installing on the fly.